# ¿Cómo puedo priorizar una ejecución sobre otra en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, optimización

Tengo ejecutando una sentencia insert, como puedo ejecutar otra(sentencia) al mismo tiempo mientras esta sigue ejecutándose. Es decir quiero que mientras se esta ejecutando el insert en la tabla "X", pueda ejecutar otra sentencia en simultaneo, que use la misma base de datos. En pocas palabras quisiera que el SQL Server priorice esta última sentencia. El escenario que tengo es el siguiente:

---Tengo un insert ejecutándose a una tabla de mi base de datos 'MIDATABASE', es un insert que va insertar millones de datos.
---Esto de alguna forma me lagea la bd. Yo quiero hacer un

```
      alter database 'MIDATABASE'
      add filegroup 'FG1'-- en Paralelo al insert
```

pero se demora mucho en ejecutarse, quizás por que se ve afectado por el insert que esta ejecutándose.

Lo que quiero es mediante un comando o sentencia indicarle al SQLSERVER que priorice la sentencia del alter de tal modo que la ejecute sin necesidad de esperar a que se termine de ejecutar el insert.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [answer]. Tu pregunta sin un escenario más explícito, solo se puede responder con opiniones, y no es el camino correcto, en este foro.

Comment: El filegroup contiene información de la tabla (registros o índices) en la que se está insertando? Cuántos procesadores tiene definido MSSQL que puede usar? Qué versión de MSSQL es? Que se esté colgando la BD con el insert es una mala señal, posiblemente el lío no sea dar prioridad a otras ejecuciones sino ver qué recurso se está agotando y optimizar la inserción, usar herramientas que la agilicen(BULK INSERT), etc.

Comment: @Alfabravo el filegroup contendrá un file que guardara una partición futura de la tabla.  En cuanto a los procesadores eso sino sabría decirte. La versión es 2008, y el insert lo estoy haciendo desde un batch que llama a los scripts de inserción.

Comment: El batch hace sqlcmd? Eso es lo mismo que ejecutar el INSERT desde cualquier otro cliente. De nuevo, la recomendación es hacer profiling, revisar qué recurso se está agotando y optimizar la inserción. Para la configuración, revisa en SSMS, clic derecho en la instancia de MSSQL (el nodo principal en el árbol de la izquierda) y en propiedades --> General verás cuántos procesadores y memoria tiene como límite tu instancia de MSSQL. Más allá de ésto no podemos ayudarte, pues es un escenario que no puede responderse en el formato de SOes, requiere todo un proceso de diagnóstico y tuning de la BD.

Comment: Es probable que el gobernador de recursos funcione para esto, pero me parece que es demasiado complicado para una operación que no debería ser habitual.